# Need to use a variable in choosing a Tab

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I am in Excel I have collected a variable correctly.

```
Dim mysheet As String
mysheet = ActiveSheet.Name
```

mysheet has a value os in one case "Agent_State_Log20180320"  - so this part seems right.

I am trying to use it in the following places - but my syntax is off.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
(mysheet).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.ClearActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
(mysheet).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range
("C1"),SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(mysheet).AutoFilter.Sort   
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

What should I change to get this to work correctly?

Comment: Your first line should be `With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(mysheet)` and then line 2 and 3, delete the `(sheet)` part. And the, right before line `With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(mysheet).AutoFilter.Sort  ` insert a line that says `End With`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1"),SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= xlSortNormal
With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```